# Door in an infinite wall problem

Tags: summation, algorithms

- Given is a line $l$ and a start point $s$ on $l$
- A target point $t$ is placed on $l$ at an unknown location
- a point robot with start location $s$ is searching for the target point $t$. The robot can detect $t$ if it reaches $t$
- the robot does not know whether t is located to the left or right of its current position

**The question is**

- Suppose the target $t$ is located at distance $d = x + \epsilon$ (where $\epsilon$ > 0 and is really small)  to the
  right of $s$ ($x$ is an integer)

**The solution to this according the slids looks like this:**

- The robot walks 1 unit to the right along l and then back
  to s
- Then it walks 1 unit to the left along l and then back to s
- Then it walks 2 unit to the right along l and then back to s
- Then it walks 2 unit to the left along l and then back to s
- ...

Which results in the following formula:

**And this is where I get lost**

[image]

In the first line I don't understand why the algorithm has to walk $(x+1) + (x +1) + x + \epsilon$.
I do get that when we walk $x + x$ we will barely miss the target $t$ because it is located at  $x + \epsilon$. So in the next iteration we are now first walking $x+1$ to the right. Why are we not finding the target $t$ then already? Since it is located at $x+ \epsilon$  we must have found it by then already?

Comment: Sorry, what is exactly the question, and what is solution? Is it really "what distance will robot travel if it uses this algorithm?"? If so, then your solution is right (for example, if $x = 0$, it will travel just $\epsilon$, not $2 + \epsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm, which is based on a worst case scenario, is accurate.

WLOG, the robot always makes his first move to the right.

Consider two examples:

1. $x = 0$ and $t$ is located $\epsilon$ **to the left**.

   First, the robot uses up two units going to the right and then returning.

   Then, the robot travels $\epsilon$ to the left and finds the target.
2. The target is located $x + \epsilon$ **and** when the robot is  searching by the steps $x + x$, the robot begins by traveling **towards** $\epsilon.$ Here, the robot just misses the target.

   Then, when the robot is searching by the steps $(x + 1) + (x + 1)$, the robot is looking in the *wrong direction*.  So the robot journeys $(x + 1)$ **away** from the target and then returns to the origin via the journey $(x + 1).$

   Then, the robot starts on a search of (potentially) $(x + 2)$ out in the same direction where the target is located.  During this journey, the robot finds the target after traveling $(x + \epsilon).$

Comment: This made everything so clear. The point was, that the robot is going (x+1) away from the target. Thanks a lot!